# Error in Visual Studio: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i want to read out data informations from the world of warcraft armory via an API.

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace CacheBuilder
{
    class WebResult
    { //Holds the status information, and Item info for each Request
        public string Item = null;
        public string Status = null;
        public WebResult(string Status) { this.Status = Status; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private const string ITEMS_FILE = @"Items.txt";
        private const string STATUS_FILE = @"Status.txt";

        private static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
        { //Writes to our output files
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(text);
            }
        }

        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static async Task<WebResult> AccessTheWebAsync(int ItemID)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://us.battle.net/api/wow/item/" + ItemID).ConfigureAwait(false);
            WebResult wr = new WebResult(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", ItemID, (int)response.StatusCode)); //Store Item ID and response code           
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) //If Code was OK
            {
                var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var json = JsonValue.Parse(responseValue); //Parse Json with System.Json
                wr.Item = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}",
                (int)json["id"], (string)json["name"], (int)json["buyPrice"], (int)json["sellPrice"],
                (int)json["itemLevel"], (int)json["itemClass"], (int)json["itemSubClass"],
                json["isAuctionable"].ToString().Equals("true") ? 1 : 0);
            }
            return wr;
        }

        private static StringBuilder Items = new StringBuilder();
        private static StringBuilder Status = new StringBuilder();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { //Entry Point
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
            { //For Item ID's 1 through 100000
                tasks.Add(AccessTheWebAsync(i));
                if (i % 1000 == 0) //Pause until the current batch of 1000 is done
                    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); 
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            foreach (Task<WebResult> t in tasks)
            {
                Status.Append(t.Result.Status).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                if (t.Result.Item != null) Items.Append(t.Result.Item).Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }



            List<Task> fileWrites = new List<Task>() { //Output our Final Files
                WriteTextAsync(ITEMS_FILE, Items.ToString()), //Log of all Items
                WriteTextAsync(STATUS_FILE, Status.ToString()) //Log of all response codes
            };
            Task.WaitAll(fileWrites.ToArray());
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Run Completed, Time elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following message if i try the script: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional informations: An error occurred while sending the request.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the details of the Exception, does it have an InnerException? If so, what is it?

Comment: InnerException {"Die Verbindung mit dem Remoteserver kann nicht hergestellt werden."} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}  This means "It can´t establish a connection with the remote server"

Comment: This means "It can´t establish a connection with the remote server" – Hertus 1 min ago    edit

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear: it cannot reach the server. Check your network, check the address of the server, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the url works and there is no network problem ( i deactived firewall etc). Any other possibilities?

Comment: I just copied and pasted this to a new project, leaving aside System.Json which you don't explain where you got it from. This runs perfectly on my system.

Comment: I pretty sure the server is blocking you, due to the amount you request until the next pause(every 1000), 100000 requests is a lot for unauthorized user to request from a site. I hope the website didn't block you, try to pause every 3-5 requests.

Comment: Yes. The problem was the amount of pauses. Thank you!